# Access a model from a Ruby file in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote my own code that is supposed to create a new Performance (model) entry in the database. I lack basic understanding of how this is supposed to work but I dont know what to search for either.

I placed this file in my projects root directory. 
When I run the file from the command-line I get the following error:

```
    C:/rubyProjects/dads/fileParser.rb:17:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Performance (NameError)
```

This is my code:

```
 require 'date'
#require 'Performance'
#require 'performer'

file_name = File.basename("app\assets\documents\Location-2003.11.11-ArtistsName-ArtistName2.txt", ".txt") 
performance_array = file_name.split("-")

location = performance_array[0]
date = performance_array[1]


begin
   date = Date.parse(date)
rescue ArgumentError
   date = Date.parse("31-02-2010")
end

#Need to access Performance here but it fails
performance = Performance.create(file_name: file_name, 
                                      date: date,
                                  location: location)


performance_array.drop(2).each do |performer_name| 
  puts artist_name 
  #save performer in db if doesnt exist
  performer = Performer.find_by_name(performer_name)
  if performer == nil  
  performer = Performer.create(name: performer_name) 
  end

  #create performer to performance relationship
  performance.performers << performer
end
```

This is my model file \app\models\performance.rb:

```
class Performance < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :file_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 },  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
   validates :date, length: { maximum: 30 }  
   validates :location, length: { maximum: 50 }
   has_many :performer_performances, dependent: :destroy  
   has_many :performers, through: :performer_performances

   def has_performer?(performer) 
     performer_performances.find_by(performer_id: performer.id)
   end

   def include! (performer)
     performer_performances.create!(performer_id: performer.id)
   end

end
```

Comment: Do you have a model named `Performance` in `app/models` directory? Can you share the model details.

Comment: You aren't using a Module or Class? This code winds up at the top level.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I included it in the question. I test my model with rspec and it works (I use the basic test from http://ruby.railstutorial.org )

Comment: What do you mean by `run the file from the cmd`? Are you executing it like `ruby fileParser.rb` then in this case Rails environment is not loaded. So you'll have to `require` the specific class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the file using

```
$ rails runner fileParser.rb
```

Comment: it works. It's so hard to keep track of all the things when you are new to rails. (I also needed to add the directory name now that i placed the file in lib dir. so i runned the runner with `rails runner lib/script.rb` instead. Thank you so much.)

Comment: that's ok but remove the `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` you added before to avoid the file run automatically when restarting rails... again i'm not sure of this "auto run" thing :D

Answer (score 1):

Common practice for code like this in rails app is to put code into [custom rake task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks). If you depend your task on :environment task like this:

```
namespace :performance do
  desc 'print all performance file names'
  task :print => :environment do
    Performance.all.each {|perf| puts perf.file_name} 
  end
end
```

it will allow you to work with model layer of your application. And you'll be able to run this task just by

```
rake performance:print
```

command.